# Threading with Chat Servers Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a problem, if I try to solve it, it does nothing to help the issue. I am trying to make a chat server for localhost at port 5000. I have a client and a serverTCP that has most of the logic.

```
import socket
from _thread import *
from queue import Queue
import threading

def main():
    try:
        host = 'localhost'
        port = 5000
        s = socket.socket()
        s.bind((host,port))
        s.listen(10)
        #Listens for incomming connections
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            print("From connected %s: " %(str(addr)) + data)
            #data = data.upper()
            forma = '[' + str(addr) + '] ' + data
            #Undo The bellow comments if system malfunction
            #tosend = input(str("-->"))
            #print("Sending: " + tosend)
            #c.send(tosend.encode('utf-8'))
            c.send(forma.encode('utf-8'))

        print("Connection was lost with: " + str(addr))

        main()
    except ConnectionResetError as CRE:
        print(str(CRE))
        main()

    except ConnectionAbortedError as CAE:
        print(str(CAE))
        main()

    except OSError as OSE:
        print(str(OSE))
        return
    main()

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        main()
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

mtfu_l = threading.Lock()
for x in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for worker in range(20):
    q.put(worker)

q.join()
```

And, the Client One:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
inp = input("client num?")
inp2 = input("Name?")
host='localhost'

port=5000

def main(host,port):
    try:
        headers = {}
        headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((host,port))
        print('connection established with ' + host) 
        connect = True
        while connect:
            message = input("--> ")
            ss = socket.socket()
            ss.connect((host,port))
            config = '[' + inp2 + ']' + message + ' '
            while message != 'q':
                s.send(config.encode('utf-8'))
                data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                print(data)
                message = input("--> ")
                config = '[' + inp2 + ']' + message + ' '
            print('Connection was lost with ' + host)
            connect = False
        if connect != True:
            main(host,port)
    except BaseException as BE:
        print(BE)
print('Connection lost with ' + host)
main(host,port)
```

My problem is, is that I cannot have multiple users chatting with one another. I want this to be the case. I've tried threading and having multiple functions to link together, but nothing seems to work. I think you guys at stack could help me though.

Thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only bind one process/thing to a port.  You need to figure out how to route the individual connections to their given handler.

Comment: Yeah. Give me a sec... There is more to it.

Comment: Alright, you've got a lot you are trying to do here.  It looks like you are starting to trying to figure out a protocol and how threads talk to each other. If nobody else gets to it first I'll try to come up with an example of something as striped down as I can get.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zonk1024/fc3cbe01be710313184f9f77c55562e3 here is kind of an example.  The limitation of the pseudocode would be that you would have to send a message to receive new messages.  This gets into async socket connections, which is a bit complex... You'll notice that https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html doesn't mention async at all.